# How to sort list of strings by length in place using List<string>.Sort?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I would like to sort my list of strings by their length in place

```
var weasleys = new List<string>{"Bill", "Charlie", "Percy", "Fred", "George", "Ron", "Ginny"};
```

I know how to do it with `OrderBy`, but this returns a copy.

```
weasleys.OrderBy(x => x.Length)
```

I would prefer to sort in place with [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas(v=vs.110).aspx). How?

Comment: why can't you just use OrderBy like you did?

Comment: You must use custom comparer to your `T` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a [`Sort(Comparison<T>)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes a [`Comparison<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate. With that, you can just use the `CompareTo` method on the respective `Length` values:

```
weasleys.Sort((x, y) => x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length));
```

Note that unlike the LINQ `OrderBy` method, the `Sort` will alter your `weasleys` List in-place if that is your intent.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Array List...

```
public class SortStringLength : IComparer
    {
        public int Compare(Object s1, Object s2)
        {
            if (s1.ToString().Length == s2.ToString().Length)
                return String.CompareOrdinal(s1.ToString(), s2.ToString());
            if (s1.ToString().Length > s2.ToString().Length)
                return 1;
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

And, then to use the `IComparer`...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var weasleys = new ArrayList { "Bill", "Charlie", "Percy", 
                  "Fred", "George", "Ron", "Ginny" };
            var sortLength = new SortStringLength();
            weasleys.Sort(sortLength);

            foreach (var weasley in weasleys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(weasley);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

With List...

```
public class SortStringLength : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x.Length == y.Length)
            return String.CompareOrdinal(x, y);
        if (x.Length > y.Length)
            return 1;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

and usage...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var weasleys = new List<string> { "Bill", "Charlie", "Percy", 
                       "Fred", "George", "Ron", "Ginny" };
            var sortLength = new SortStringLength();
            weasleys.Sort(sortLength);

            foreach (var weasley in weasleys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(weasley);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
var weasleys = new List<string>{"Bill", "Charlie", "Percy", "Fred", "George", "Ron", "Ginny"};
var t = weasleys.OrderBy(x => x.Length).ToList<string>();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> dictionary = new List<string>() { "aaa", "aaaa", "a", "aa" };
        var orderedDic = dictionary.Select(x => new
          {
            val = x,
            length = x.Length
          }).OrderBy(x => x.length).ToList();
        dictionary = orderedDic.Select(x => x.val).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", dictionary));
     }
}
```

The approach which I have used here

1. created a list of anonymous objects with val and length property.
2. Order the list on length.

Comment: I suspect that your answer was downvoted because it is much more complicated than the accepted answer and doesn't do an in-place sort.

Comment: there are many ways to achieve the same, I have given different thought process.